# In javascript, [] === [] and [] == [] both returns false

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

why is that? I assumed it's some implicit type conversion at first, but [] == [] is also false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in javascript are Objects. Objects are compared by identity. So no two objects created by different literals (or by other means) are going to be equal (either strictly (`===`) or loosely (`==`)).

Comment: in javascript: `[] === []` equals new `Array() === new Array()` which means two instances of array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've always felt a bit uneasy about those terms. Thanks for the heads up.